# whats wrong with this code? it always returns savedInstanceState as null

Tags: java, android

This code always returns `savedInstanceState` as `null`

```
public class DemoidActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, android.view.View.OnClickListener  {

EditText t1=null;
EditText t2=null;
EditText t3=null;
EditText t4=null;
String data1 = null,data2=null,data3=null;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    t1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    t2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    t3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    t4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);



}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with HTML. Please edit the question to re-tag.

Comment: The code doesn't *return* anything. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and clarify your question.

Comment: Are you talking about `savedInstanceState` coming into `onCreate` being `null`? It should be `null` when the `Activity` is first created. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: do you mean that you are getting an NPE when invoking onCreate?

Answer (score 2):

Their is nothing wrong with the code as such. The reason why you are getting the `savedInstanceState` as `null` in your `onCreate()` method is because your activity is created for the first time and so there won't be any saved state as such.

It will only be set if you implement the method onSaveInstanceState().
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

Answer (score 1):

It means that your activity's state is never saved.
Try to override the `onSaveInstanceState()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //Put your stuff in the bundle
}
```

Then use it to retrieve data/activity sate whether in the `onCreate()` method or in the `onRestoreInstanceState()` one:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    //Retrieve data
}
```